# How can I rearrange data sorted in rows into data sorted into columns?

Tags: python, list, file, for-loop, formatting

I have a text file arranged in the following way:

```
Time  x1  y1  z1  x2  y2  z2 ... x54  y54  z54
0   x1(0) ect.   x2(0)   .       .    .    .
1   x1(1)    .   .   .   .       .    .    .
.    .   .   .   .   .   .       .    .    .
1e10
```

and instead I would like it to look like this:

```
Time  x    y     z

0   x1(0) y1(0) z1(0) 
0   x2(0) y2(0) z2(0)
.
.
0  x54(0) y54(0) z54(0)
1   x1(1) y1(1) z1(1)
.
.
.
1e10 x1(1e10) y1(1e10) z1(1e10)
. 
.
1e10 x54(1e10) y54(1e10) z54(1e10)
```

I initially thought to do:

```
     with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
     lines = f.readlines()
     time = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
     x1 = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]
     x2 = [float(line.split()[2]) for line in lines]
```

ect. until I have 1 + 3 x 54 lists. Then I would have to combine the lists (separately for x, y and z lists) i.e. [x1(0), x2(0),...,x54(0),x1(1), ect.]. This seems very inefficient and since my file is so large I think I would have issues here. Does anyone have any better ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to use the library `pandas` to work with table-formatted data

Answer (score 0):

Can you use pandas ?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.txt")

df.T
```

Comment: I don't want to transpose the data so this won't work